# How to create alias for particular (new/existing) function in glibc

Tags: c, linux, build, glibc

For some reasons I wish to create alias to function

```
pthread_mutex_trylock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex);
```

from the glibc to alias named

```
lab_pthread_mutex_trylock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex);
```

I try add

```
weak_alias (__pthread_mutex_trylock, lab_pthread_mutex_trylock)
```

in the file *pthread_mutex_trylock.c* (editing source code of the library) and then

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user/glibc
make
make install
```

After that I compile my program like

```
  gcc \
  -L "/home/user/glibc/lib" \
  -I "/home/user/glibc/include" \
  -Wl,--rpath="/home/user/glibc/lib" \
  -Wl,--dynamic-linker="/home/user/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" \
  -std=c11 \
  -o main.out \
  -v \
  main.c \
  -pthread \
;
ldd ./main.out
./main.out
```

The ldd script show me that some functions (from default libc) are really from my build of glibc, but use lab_pthread_mutex_trylock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex) causes error.

glibc has very complicated structure and I have quite weak knowledge about build management so I feel that lot of things I should to do was missed by me. Please, help me, it's very important for me...

Error by gcc:

```
gcc -L "/ home / anahel / glibc-test / lib" -I "/ home / anahel / glibc-test / include" -Wl, - rpath = "/ home / anahel / glibc-test / lib" -Wl , - dynamic-linker = "/ home / anahel / glibc-test / lib / ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" -std = c11 -o main.out main.c -pthread

/ usr / bin / ld: /tmp/ccivqLEz.o: in the "main" function:
main.c :(. text + 0x1b): undefined reference to "lab_pthread_mutex_trylock"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The steps I did in glibc sources:

1) If file glibc-2.31/nptl/pthread_mutex_trylock.c I added

```
weak_alias (__pthread_mutex_trylock, lab_pthread_mutex_trylock)
```

2) In file glibc-2.31/sysdeps/nptl/pthread.h I added

```
extern int lab_pthread_mutex_trylock (pthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
 __THROWNL __nonnull ((1));
```

right after

```
/* Try locking a mutex.  */
extern int pthread_mutex_trylock (pthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
     __THROWNL __nonnull ((1));
```

Comment: Which error does it cause? Did you mind to declare the function somehow?

Comment: @Ctx, undefined reference. It's my university task - implement pthread_mutex_trylock, all of the linux lib functions are allowed besides pthread_mutex_trylock function. So I dicided just rename function in glibc, and make this lib for use

Comment: Not likely a problem (yet...) but are you also renaming the function the the `pthread.h` header file so code that uses it has a proper prototype?  Also:  glibc is one complex beast.  It possible that it's a lot more complicated to rename a function than just changing a weak alias and a maybe a reference or two.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I updated my question...

Comment: In sources i see names like __pthread_mutex_lock, but where defined external interface?

Comment: OK, lets try bad way. Somebody knows how to replace all occurrences in all files in dir recursively? =)

Comment: find . -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/search/replace/g'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

> `undefined reference to "lab_pthread_mutex_trylock"`

means that the `lab_pthread_mutex_trylock` is not *exported* from `/home/user/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0`. You can confirm this with:

```
nm -D /home/user/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0 | grep lab_pthread_mutex_trylock
```

(expect no output if my guess is correct).

The likely reason it's not exported: GLIBC build process tightly controls which functions are exported, and what version they have, via a linker script (which is generated by combining several `Version` files).

In particular, you very likely need to add `lab_pthread_mutex_trylock` to the `glibc-2.31/nptl/Versions` file.

Comment: you was absolutely right! this is the only step that remained in order for everything to work! 1) edit pthread_mutex_trylock.c 2) edit pthread.h 3) and add lab_pthread_mutex_trylock to nptl / Versions file. I spent several days trying to find the answer.  Thank you so much!

Comment: After I recursively changed the names of the function and renamed pthread_mutex_trylock () to lab_pthread_mutex_trylock (), when building, I got an error something like "there is no name pthread_mutex_trylock in the file / usr / include / x86_64-linux-gnu / c ++ / bits 9 /gthr-default.h and /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/gthr-posix.h "

Comment: @penny You can't just rename the standard function, because other code (headers included in GCC here) *depends* on it. Your question created an alias, and *that* should be ok.